# API Gateway Response time issue

Tags: websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS API Gateway and passing one large CSV file to backend Lambda. Due to limitation of AWS API gateway response time that is 30 seconds, it's not processing.

I explored web socket option but it's an expensive option because connections need to open all the time.

Can someone please advice me best solution to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: We don't have enough information to provide a solution.  What is the client?  Is it a webapp, a shell script, etc?  Why does it need to be an API call instead of maybe uploading the file to an s3 bucket via the AWS CLI or AWS SDK then use the CLI or SDK to trigger a Lambda that consumes the file from the bucket?

Comment: its a webapp. End user needs to provide inputs to trigger backend lambda. Those inputs could in CSV format or one single input like employee ID.

Comment: So if it's a large file I would make it an asynchronous process.  I would use the AWS SDK to upload the file to a bucket ( asynchronously ) then trigger the lambda to consume from the bucket.  I would remove the API Gateway completely.  The file is simply too large to sent via a REST service to API Gateway